# Add mvn classifier for POM packaging

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Today Maven allows the creations of various versions of a JAR using the classifier option of Maven JAR plugin. Just want to know if there's any plugins to do the same for POM packaging? So that I can have multiple versions of the same POM artefacts distinguished by classifiers.

Comment: There is no maven classifier for POM packaging.

Comment: The type is simply `pom`... why do you use classifiers?

Comment: No. What is your use case?

Comment: this wasn't a valid use case for maven, since it essentials it the same as far as maven is concerned. Solved my use case through Jenkins.